# Check all to highlight all rows in a table

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following HTML/jQuery code where my CheckAll process box works fine but at the same time. I would also like to highlight all row in my table when this CheckAll checkbox is clicked and obviously
un-highlight when the the CheckAll box is deselected.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it going. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
<tr>
<th id=" " class="t12subheader">
<input id="checkAll" type="checkbox">
</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="t12datavalue" align="center" style=""><input type="checkbox" value="123" name="f01"></td>
  <td class="t12datavalue" style="">123</td>
  <td class="t12datavalue" style="">333</td>
  <td class="t12datavalue" style="">Alex</td>
  <td class="t12datavalue" style="">Smith</td>
</tr>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkAll").click(function() {
      $("input[name='f01']").attr('checked', 
                                $('#checkAll').is(':checked'));
      $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlight');
    }); 

 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated solution with extra features**

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.attr('checked')) {
        self.closest('tr').nextAll().addClass('highlight').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        self.closest('tr').nextAll().removeClass('highlight').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    }
});

$("table :checkbox").not("#checkAll").click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var checked = self.attr('checked');
    self.closest('tr').toggleClass('highlight');
    if (!checked) {
        $("#checkAll").attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

- Toggles highlight when the check all or any single row check is clicked
- Unchecks check all whenever any single row is unchecked
- Works for any number of rows

Comment: thanks for this. This seems to work but my there seems to be an issues that when you do a Check All and then individually uncheck a record below and then uncheck the Check All checkbox, the individual record you uncheck then becomes highlighted. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
$(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlight');
```

to

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll().toggleClass('highlight');
```

works.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjkg5/4/)

Comment: only seems to highlight the very first row only but not the remaining rows - any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @tonsils I changed the next() to nextAll(). NOw it should work.[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjkg5/5/)